apply " equivalence file " to a dataframe
Lets say we have a master dataframe and a equivalence file.
We want to apply the changes indicated in the " equivalence file " in a column of the master dataframe.
For example:
Master dataframe:



ColA
ColB




A
1


B
2


C
3



" equivalence file ":



ini
fin




1
111


3
333



The desired output, after applying the changes indicated in the " equivalence file " to the master dataframe should be:



ColA
ColB




A
111


B
2


C
333



Ideally, define a python function (def :) for the subject...

Perform a merge and then filter to replace ColB if a valid fin exists:
master = pd.DataFrame(data = {'ColA': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'ColB': [1, 2, 3]})
equiv = pd.DataFrame(data = {'ini': [1, 3], 'fin': [111, 333]})

result = master.merge(equiv, how = 'left', left_on = 'ColB', right_on = 'ini')

equiv_exists = ~result['fin'].isna()
result.loc[equiv_exists, 'ColB'] = result.loc[equiv_exists, 'fin']
result = result[['ColA', 'ColB']]


Load your "equivalence file" into a dict and use Series.replace():
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]])
   0  1
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3

>>> eqv = {"1": "111", "3": "333"}
>>> df1[1] = df1[1].replace(eqv)
>>> df1
   0    1
0  a  111
1  b    2
2  c  333
>>>

To demonstrate loading the data from CSV (inlined here, but it's whatever):
import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
ColA,ColB
a,1
b,2
c,3
"""))

eqv_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
1,111
3,333
"""), header=None)

eqv = dict(zip(eqv_df[0], eqv_df[1]))

df1["ColC"] = df1["ColB"].replace(eqv)

print(df1)

prints out
  ColA  ColB  ColC
0    a     1   111
1    b     2     2
2    c     3   333


and how about treatment both files as dataframes? is it possible? Thanks of course!

You can get a dict like that out of a dataframe you read from disk, yes.
